# OAuth JIRA authentication flow fails

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, jira

So i've created an app on jira's developers console and recieved a Client ID and a secret.
According to jira-oauth docs Im sending a `get` request from the browser

```
https://auth.atlassian.com/authorize?
  audience=api.atlassian.com&
  client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&
  scope=REQUESTED_SCOPE_ONE%20REQUESTED_SCOPE_TWO&
  redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP_CALLBACK_URL&
  state=YOUR_USER_BOUND_VALUE&
  response_type=code&
  prompt=consent
```

This fire the callback uri with a long string as query param:

```
https://9bd3-203-114-123-134.ap.ngrok.io/?state=%24%7BYOUR_USER_BOUND_VALUE%7D&code=
```

Appending it to the access_token `post` request

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://auth.atlassian.com/oauth/token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
"grant_type": "authorization_code",
"client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
"client_secret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
"code": "YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE",
"redirect_uri": "https://YOUR_APP_CALLBACK_URL"}'
```

This eventually returns a 404 error with title message and description as follows:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "failed to retrieve client"
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? all the credentials I've entered are rechecked 10 times and most of it actually copied so little room for typos.
Thank you for the help